# Ipython installing notebook extensions

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have tried for the past couple of hours to install the nbextensions found in the following repo `https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions` to no avail.

The instructions say to run either `conda` or `setup.py` i have done both and both throw errors

i went to my `~/.ipython/nbextensions/` folder ran both `conda` and `setup.py` and errors come out

`conda build IPython-notebook-extensions
Error: no such directory: /Users/username/.ipython/nbextensions/IPython-notebook-extensions`

my .ipython/nbextensions folder has all of the folders and files found in the `nbextensions` folder in github `https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/tree/master/nbextensions`

how in the world should i go about to install/enable these extensions? the instructions are a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
git clone https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions.git
cd IPython-notebook-extensions
python setup.py install
cd ..
rm -r IPython-notebook-extensions
```

Comment: Thanks! i was getting a `ImportError: No module named yaml` error so it leave this here for future reference for others: make sure you install `pyyaml` for this to work properly